# bluetooth cant find logitech keyboard

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, 22.04, bluetooth, logitech

I used my keyboard Logitech K375s with unifying and bluetooth over a years in different OS. This time I tried to bt pair it on MSI Alpha B5EEK notebook, but bluetooth simply can't find it. Other devices, like smartphone or mouse, works well without problems of finding it or pairing it. I'am using it with USB Unifying, but i need that for another device.
Kubuntu 22.04 LTS kernel 5.19

I tried to reinstall bluetoothctl, drivers for wifi/bt, but nothing helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it is Bluetooth.? If it is using the unifying dongle from Logitech it is not BT it is RF and must match the keyboard.

Comment: This keyboard works with both USB Unifying receiver and Bluetooth. That Unifying USB works well - there is also software for it (Solaar). But if I want to connect this keyboard with bluetooth, syste cannot find it. :-(

Comment: OK mine is only RF.

Comment: After new system updates this week with kernel 5.19 and other sysem parts, that solved problem with BT connestion to other devices (means no USB wireless).
ADD: I hoped, those updates will also solve problem about sleep mode function.